# Destination of carbonyl compounds free toluene

Tags: purification, distillation

I am currently in the process of trying to get toluene free of carbonyl compounds using a distillation processes with DNPH.

Unfortunately I am no distillation expert. And am running into some problems.

The method is take one liter of toluene and 4g of dnph and 0.5 ml of HCl. all technical grade. Reflux for 2 hours and distill. Discard the first 50 ml.

DNPH has a amount of water. That's I assume you need to discard the first 50ml

Apparently when distilling you need a fractional column. Don't know why but assume that compound with a boiling point that differs from the clean toluene.

Now the problem is I do not get clean toluene. I think this has something to do with the boiling point of hydrazine. This  has almost the same boiling point as toluene. How would one get better separation in a distillation process?

Comment: If you mean DNPH for [2,4-dinitrophenylhydrazine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,4-Dinitrophenylhydrazine) (which is solid), its boiling point is way higher than that of toluene. Also, use of that in distillation process raised safety hazards.

Comment: You are correct it is 2,4 dinitrophenylhydrazine. I know it's a safety concern. But this is how it's described in the unclear method. Dnph does dissolve at a certain temperature in toluene. Does  dissolve poorly in tolueen at room temperature. Needed to find that out as well. Any guesses on how to solve the problem? It's like destilling de last 4 procent of water out of ethanol I believe.

Comment: Ensure not to distill to the dryness when DNPH present.

Comment: Yes according to the method I need to discard 50 ml in the beginning and need to distill to about  75% of the volume added  at beginning of the distillation